# Showing an estimated delivery date

Tags: magento-1.9, date

I am trying to show an estimated delivery date to my shipping methods, I currently have this code which is displaying the date that is it today in the format of Thursday-November-2014

```
<?php $currentTimestamp = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time());
        echo 'Estimated delivery date ' ;
        echo $deliverydate = date('l-F-Y', $currentTimestamp);?>
```

But how can I get it to add 2 days on to the date and display that?

Thank you if you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
$currentTimestamp = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time());
```

use this:

```
$currentTimestamp = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time() + 2 * 24 * 60 * 60);
```

Comment: cheers i will try it in a min, could you just explain to me what *24 *60 * 60 means as i assume the 2 is 2 days

Comment: 2 days * 24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds, I'll give you the no math version in a minute

Comment: 2 = 2 days, 24 = hours in a day, 60 = minutes in an hour, 60 = seconds in a minute. Since `time()` returns a value in seconds, you need to add the number of seconds that equals to 2 days. I could have just said `+ 172800` but then you would have said "WHAAAT?" :)

Comment: makes sense now i didnt know it returned the values in seconds, sorry to ask for the explanination but i like to learn fixes rather than just use other peoples code. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

`Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->addDay(2);`

To format it, have a look at the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.date.constants.html#zend.date.constants.selfdefinedformats) , the one you gave in your question looks like Dayname-Monthname-FullYear which looks a little weird

Answer (score 0):

Following code will give you the date after 2 days .

```
<?php 
$currentTimestamp = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time());
echo 'Estimated delivery date ' ;
echo $deliverydate = date('l-F-Y', $currentTimestamp);
$datenew =  strtotime('2 day', $currentTimestamp);
echo date('l-F-Y',$datenew);
?>
```